# Comparing the Values of Two Table Columns to Display a List MVC4

Tags: database, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

I have two tables within a database, one table is called Booking. This table will record data that a user can input via a form on the webstie. The other table is called Account, this table will record information regarding the login information of a user to the website.

When a user successfully logs into the website they are "Redirected" to a new View called Manage. Within the manage view I want to be able to display a table of just the information from the Booking table that relates to that particular account.

I think that in my Controller, within the Manage ActionResult I need to compare the values within the BookingEmail column of my Booking Table with the values within the AccountEmail column of my Account Table. If there is a match then a list of the information which relates to that email is shown in the manage view.

I have an idea of how to go about it but actually making the code for it too work I don't know. I am new to MVC4.

Please Help.

Booking Model:

```
public partial class Booking
{
    public int BookingId { get; set; }
    public string BookingFirstname { get; set; }
    public string BookingSurname { get; set; }
    public string BookingEmail { get; set; }
    public string BookingMobileTel { get; set; }
    public string BookingHomeTel { get; set; }
    public int BookingAge { get; set; }
    public int BookingPassengers { get; set; }
    public int DepartureId { get; set; }
    public int ArrivalId { get; set; }
}
```

Account Model:

```
public partial class Account
{
    public System.Guid AccountId { get; set; }
    public string AccountEmail { get; set; }    // Primary Key
    public string AccountPassword { get; set; }
    public string AccountPasswordSalt { get; set; }
}
```

Removed validation for a clearer picture.

In my Account Controller, in a `[HttpPost]` method for LogIn:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogIn(Account user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (isValid(user.AccountEmail, user.AccountPassword))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.AccountEmail, false);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");                            
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login Data does not exist, Please Register");
            }
        }

        return View(user);
    }
```

UPDATE:

In order to go to the Manage View, which is in HomeController I have used this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogIn(Account user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (isValid(user.AccountEmail, user.AccountPassword))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.AccountEmail, false);

                bool hasBooking = db.Bookings.Where(b => b.BookingEmail == user.AccountEmail).Any();

                if (hasBooking == true)
                    return RedirectToAction("Manage", "Home");
                else
                    return RedirectToAction("Book", "Home");                            
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login Data does not exist, Please Register");
            }
        }

        return View(user);
    }
```

UPDATE:

So I have passed the AccountEmail from the AccountController to the HomeController using TempData:

Account Controller:

```
TempData["user"] = user.AccountEmail;
```

Home Controller:

```
public ActionResult Manage()
{
    var user = TempData["user"] as string;
    IEnumerable<Booking> bookings = db.Bookings.Where(b => b.BookingEmail == user);
    return View(bookings);
}
```

Comment: It really has nothing to do with MVC. Are you using EF?

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes I am.

Comment: We really need to see the models to have any hope of helping you.

Comment: @Glitch100 added the models of the tables.

Comment: Its a little unclear because your `Account` has a property `BookingId` suggesting a user can only have one booking. But if there is a relationship between `Account.AccountEmail` and `Booking.Email` then the query would be `var bookings = db.Bookings.Where(b => b.BookingEmail == theUsersAccountEmail)` However I suspect there might be problems with you table design - why would you not have `FirstName`, `LastName` etc in the `Account` table rather than having it repeated multiple times in the `Booking` table?

Comment: @StephenMuecke When a user makes a booking they have to include all the details in the Booking class. But for simplicity when they register/login they just have to enter their email and password. I have editied the Account class to exclude the BookingId.

Comment: Based on your edit it would be `where a.BookingEmail == user.AccountEmail` (and do your expect the user to change there name? :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke So how would I be able to compare the inputted user.AccountEmail which is of type string with the values in the column BookingEmail and if there is a match RedirectToAction("Manage", "Home")?

Comment: If you just wanting to check if there are any matches, then it could be `bool hasBooking = db.Bookings.Where(b => b.BookingEmail == user.AccountEmail).Any();`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks, this works. So there is a Booking been made that uses the same email is the email used to sign in. I now want to display a table for just that users email address. So I need to find a way in which I can display just a row from the Booking table and that row must be the row of the BookingEmail.

Comment: That's `IEnumerable<Booking> bookings = db.Bookings.Where(b => b.BookingEmail == user.AccountEmail); return View(bookings);` assuming a user could have made multiple bookings, or if there is only one, then `Booking booking = db.Bookings.Where(b => b.BookingEmail == user.AccountEmail).FirstOrDefault(); return View(booking);`